# Using Firebase for Authenticating REST API

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a application say 'ABC' which provides a service. That service is accessed by some other applications say 'PQR' and 'XYZ'.
Is there any way to use firebase for user authentication in application ABC? I gone through firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/) which provides REST support but it requires API_KEY which is bounded to specific ip addresses and not possible to provide same key to applications XYZ and PQR.

The architecture which I was planning is:

1. Users of application PQR and XYZ will login to firebase using email and password.
2. Users of application PQR and XYZ will communicate to services of ABC using the session created by firebase.

Answer (score 0):

When a user authentication with Firebase Authentication they get a token that identifies them. You client app can send this token to the new service you've created, which then [verifies that the ID token is valid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). Once you know the token is valid, you can be certain it identifies the user.

Comment: Yeah but how? how to authenticate user with firebase when there is no web UI available. I just have rest API.